# Making block/Character move "X px" when "W or w" is only once when pressed, and not continue walking when "W and w" is held down

Tags: java, processing

I want to make my Rectangle/Character move "X px's" when I press "W or w" but only once. And not continue moving when "W and w" is held down. I have tried making a "Key Released" function with a variable that changes when "W or w" is pressed. But it didn't really work, it only made it so the Rectangle/Character moved "X px's" once and then would not move in that direction after. I in short want the Rectangle/Character to move 50px each time you "Click" a button, sort of a step by step. And not a fluid movement. Anyone who can help? 
The code is written in Java, Processing.

```java
class Character {

float x = 0;
float y = 0;

//VV Movement VV

void move() {
    if (keyPressed) {
        if (key == 'w' || key == 'W') {
            //terms, move forward/up, Y-axel.
            y -= 50;
        }
    }
    if (keyPressed) {
        if (key == 'a' || key == 'A') {
            //terms, move right, X-axel.
            x -= 50;
        }
    }
    if (keyPressed) {
        if (key == 's' || key == 'S') {
            //terms, move backwards/down, Y-axel.
            y += 50;
        }
    }
    if (keyPressed) {
        if (key == 'd' || key == 'D') {
            //terms, move left, X-axel.
            x += 50;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I want to make my Rectangle/Character move [...] but only once

Add a [`keyPressed()`](https://processing.org/reference/keyPressed_.html) event and call `move` from the event, but do not call it in [`draw()`](https://processing.org/reference/draw_.html).

Note `keyPressed` is called once every time a key is pressed. So the character moves only once, when a key is pressed. But since the operating systems may handle key repeats, the last pressed key ha to be stored. If the same key is pressed again before `keyReleased` occurs, it has to be skipped. e.g.:

```java
Character ch = new Character();
```

```java
int lastKey = 0;
void keyPressed() {
    if (lastKey != key) {
        lastKey = key; 
        ch.move();
    }
}

void keyReleased() {
    lastKey = 0;
}
```

In the example `ch` assumed to be your instance of `Character`.

Comment: i know i put it outside of draw and it partially worked. but when i hold the "W or w" it moves multiple steps instead of just one. is there a way to make it move once even if i hold the "W or w" down?

Comment: When i press and release the 'W' button it moves 50px, as intended. But when i press the 'W' button and dont release it, it moves more than once; 50px,50px,50px,... I added print(key); but it still does it.

Comment: this is how my code looks were it calls the objects.                                      
   void setup() {

  g = new gubbe();
  //Canvas 
  size( 800, 800 );
  strokeWeight( 10 );
  frameRate( 30 );
  //*
}

void keyPressed(){
  g.move();
  print(key);
  }
void draw() {
  //Canvas färg
  background( 100 );
  //*
  g.Fight();
  g.display();
  g.checkEdges();
  g.BarsDisplay();
  g.HealthDisplay();
  g.XpDisplay();
  
}

Comment: found it. And it worked! thanks man. Saved me alot of time there. Im a beginner in Java as you can prob. tell.

Comment: You could have done the move on the keyReleased rather than the key pressed so it only did a move on release and not on key press or key hold... Or maybe on the keyDown rather than keyPressed